# Does `git archive` use the wrong file timestamp?

Tags: git, timestamps

It seems `git archive` creates a tarball with wrong file modification timestamps, resulting in `tar` complaining when unpacking:

```
$ cd repository
$ git archive -o repository.tar.gz master .
$ find /target/dir -type f -delete
$ tar -C /target/dir -xvf repository.tar.gz
some/file.txt
tar: some/file.txt: time stamp 2014-10-29 13:09:52 is 49.814349986 s in the future
another/file.txt
tar: another/file.txt: time stamp 2014-10-29 13:09:52 is 49.813794938 s in the future
```

This all happens within seconds *on a single machine*.

Comment: The timestamps in the tar file are supposed to be exactly the timestamp of the commit you supplied (`master`). What is the timestamp of that commit, and is it equal to that timestamp `2014-10-29 13:09:52` which is in the future? Display the raw value with for example `git log -n1 --format=format:%at,%ct master`.

Comment: Yep, that's it - the commit was at that time.

Comment: @Celada I suggest writing an answer.

Comment: Make sure you don't have clock skew between commits fetched from a different machine, and make sure your timezones are correct.

Comment: @o11c I agree that the culprit here is likely clock skew. However, timezones don't need to be correct. When `tar` is reporting timestamps in the future, it's comparing UTC time to UTC time, so timezones don't enter into it.

Comment: @Celada It's not that hard for an inexperienced user to change the local clock when physically moving between timezones, instead of just changing the active timezone and leaving the clock alone.

Comment: It's a 50 second difference, so timezones do not enter into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you give a commit ID or tag ID (or branch name, as you've done here) to `git archive`, the commit time as recorded in the referenced commit object is used as the modification time of each file in the archive.

It looks like the latest commit on `master` was at `2014-10-29 13:09:52`, which must have been in the future relative to the moment when you ran `git archive`. Perhaps that commit was fetched from a remote repository with an incorrect clock, or the local clock is incorrect?